# Django Multipart Image Upload: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-rest-framework

While uploading an ImageFile to a Django REST backend I am encountering the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /user/addimage/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", liner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187,e
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185,e
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 5w
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, w
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dh
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in hn
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dh
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2/user_profiles/views.py", line 92, in post
    profile_stored = file_system_instance.save('profile_' + data['first_name'] + ".jpg", request.FIL)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 54, e
    return self._save(name, content)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 351,e
    for chunk in content.chunks():
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/base.py", line 81, in s
    data = self.read(chunk_size)
  File "/home/neuron/genie2_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 16, in>
    read = property(lambda self: self.file.read)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
[01/Aug/2017 14:14:22] "POST /user/addimage/ HTTP/1.1" 500 18686
```

My View:

```
class AddImage(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        user_serialized = ContactNumberUserSerializer(instance=self.request.user)
        data = user_serialized.data
        instance = ContactNumberUser.objects.get(contact=data['contact'])

        profile_img_instance = ImageFile(request.FILES.get('profile_pic'))
        file_system_instance = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
        instance.profile_pic = file_system_instance.save('profile_' + data['first_name'] + ".jpg", profile_img_instance)
        instance.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Am I doing it completely wrong somehow? If yes, please suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Django REST Framework 3 deprecated the request.FILES option.You can use request.data for the imagefield.

Change

```
request.FILES.get('profile_pic')
```

to

```
request.data.get('profile_pic')
```

If you defined ImageField or FileField , you do not need to upload file manually. Django will do it for you

Instead of this code,

```
profile_img_instance = ImageFile(request.FILES.get('profile_pic'))
file_system_instance = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) 
instance.profile_pic = file_system_instance.save('profile_' + data['first_name'] + ".jpg", profile_img_instance)
```

Directly assign image to field,

```
instance.profile_pic = request.data.get('profile_pic')
```

Also make sure your model field look like this,

```
class Model(models.Model):
   profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile')
```

Comment: I tried it, still no change. It throws me the same error.

Comment: are you sure image is passed ? print request.data.get('profile_pic') and check on console